# Font of List of Figures

Tags: table-of-contents

Actually when I am generating a list of figures, the words in figure captions which are actually in italic font, are also in italic in list of figures. 
The question is : How can I generate a list of figure with all entries in plain text, while maintaining italics in figures' captions. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The answer depends on how you create the captions and the table of contents. Therefore, please provide a complete small document illustrating your problem; it should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. Use the [edit button](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/335852/edit) left below your post to add the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ssuming a standard class is used, package `caption` comes to help.

[image: tahirsengineCaptionFontLofFont]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=it}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\section{Wombat}
\captionof{figure}{If there would be a picture, it would show a duck.}
\end{document}
```